# JTable записать данные ИЗ таблицы в массив Java

Tags: java, jtable

Всем доброе время суток! 
Как я знаю, при создании таблицы есть возможность перегрузкой отправить двумерный массив данных и одномерный с названиями столбцов.

```
JTable table = new JTable(data,headlines);
```

Можно ли как-то вернуть НОВЫЕ данные таблицы в массив?

Comment: что такое новые данные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо реализовать `AbstractTableModel` или `DefaultTableModel` и в тот момент когда у вас меняются данные извне вызвать `fireTableDataChanged`. Переопределить `isCellEditable` для редактируемых ячеек. Переопределить `setValueAt` менять данные и вызывать  `fireTableDataChanged`.

Вашу модель вы передадите в JTable и тогда она будет обновляться автоматически.

Comment: Не против, если обращусь к вам в лс с вопросами по вашему ответу?Некоторые методы не знаю, сейчас разберусь

Comment: я ответил на ваш вопрос? если да - принимайте.

Comment: не знаю, реализовываю

Comment: @Mikhail_Vaysman Не пойму, как касается isCellEditable(проверяющий, редактируема ли ячейка) и setValueAt( для ввода значений в ячейку) и метод перерисовки fireTableDataChanged к заданию? Не вижу связи :(
Мне ведь нужно вывести сохранить новые данные в массив

Comment: вы сделали AbstractTableModel?

Comment: @Mikhail_Vaysman нет, использовал DefaultTableModel

Comment: @Mikhail_Vaysman зачем переопределять setValueAt я понял, при изменении ячейки- с помощью метода вводим новые данные в массив , а вот зачем isCellEditable? или перерисовка с помощью fireTableDataChanged?

Comment: Если у вас не все ячейки редактируемые, вам нужно это как-указать таблице? И если у вас данные поменялись, то вам надо перерисовать таблицу?

Comment: @Mikhail_Vaysman что вы имеете ввиду когда говорите переопределить "isCellEditable" что мы должны изменить в переопределенном методе?

Comment: Если ячейку можно редактировать он вернёт истину, а если нельзя - ложь.

Comment: @Mikhail_Vaysman разве этот метод не работает так же, не переопределяя его?

Comment: @Mikhail_Vaysman может просто добавить условие isCellEditable в переопределенный setValueAt?

Comment: Если у вас все ячейки редактируемые, то можно не переопределять

Comment: @Mikhail_Vaysman можно последний вопрос? Не подскажите, как можно переопределить стандартный метод таблицы (в том же классе), если класс уже наследует JFrame?

Comment: Какой класс у вас наследует JFrame?

Comment: @Mikhail_Vaysman класс, содержащий компоненты, включая таблицу и методы для работы с ней

Comment: Сделайте новый вопрос с кодом. Так мне не понятно.

Comment: @Mikhail_Vaysman
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610636/Переопределение-setvalueat