# Переопределение setValueAt

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Как в этом классе переопределить `setValueAt()`, относящийся к `TableModel`?

```
class Dz_42 extends JFrame {
    final JTable table;

    Dz_42() {
        //здесь находился код, не относящийся к вопросу
    }//end constructor

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dz_42 dzObj = new Dz_42();
    }
}//class
```

Comment: спасибо за замечание, исправил

Comment: В каком классе? У кого вы хотите что-то переопределить?

Comment: Если вы хотите переопределить этот метод [setValueAt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setValueAt(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)), то делать это нужно в классе, который `extends JTable`.

Comment: @Regent а не в TableModel?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman автор написал про "`setValueAt()`, относящийся к `JTable`", поэтому я так и ответил. Если автор вдруг имел в виду интерфейс `TableModel`, то стоит исправить вопрос. Пока что, как по мне, не очень понятно что же автору нужно на самом деле.

Comment: @Regent необходимо переопределить setValueAt() таким образом, чтобы при добавлении данных- они вводились еще и в массив.
Можно как-то переопределить метод анонимным способом, не стирая extends JFrame и не добавляя новый файл с классом?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman это класс, в котором будут происходить действия из моего прошлого вопроса, о котором мы говорили

Comment: @VladislavSolopov я имел ввиду переопределить setValueAt в TableModel, а не в JTable.

Comment: @VladislavSolopov мне такие методы неизвестны. А в чём проблема с созданием ещё одного класса?